# Access Pixel 2 XL "taimen" through ADB (while in the process of installing lineageOS)

Tags: adb, fastboot, linux, lineageos, nexus

I followed [this guide](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/taimen/install) until `fastboot flash boot boot.img` included and OK

Then reboot in recovery mode
Then *"Now tap Factory Reset, then Format data / factory reset"* included and OK

**/!\** BUT since then, *adb* can't see my Nexus phone (Pixel 2XL - "taimen"), neither is it visible with `lsusb` when in recovery mode. I tried *"Apply from ADB"* or *"Enable ADB"* via lineageOS recovery mode gui, but `adb devices` returns an empty list :-|

When in fastboot mode, I can see the phone via lsusb :

```
[stan@stan-xps139305 ~]$ lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 18d1:4ee0 Google Inc. Nexus/Pixel Device (fastboot)
...
```

Is there a way to get my phone recognized by *adb*, or to flash it via *fastboot* directly... ?
Also can *udev rules* help... ?

N.B. : `SECURE BOOT` is `ON` (don't know if it can be blocking...)

[EDIT] >>>

I also tried several USB cables/ports already :-|
I'll try on another computer too ASAP

I just fear the phone USB mode is kinda stuck while in recovery mode.
This page shows the possible modes for pixel phone (mine is PIXEL 2 XL): https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/18D1
4ee2 instead of 4ee0 is what I expect, but hell no.
How is it that I can see the phone with `lsusb` while in fastboot mode, but cannot see it at all while in recovery ?
<<<

[NEW EDIT] >>>
these are the *udev* rules I've set:

```
#GOogle Inc. 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee0", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee2", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="d001", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

<<<

Comment: If you enable adb or start side-loading mode (Apply from ADB) at least lsusb should show some device. May be the recovery has a bug, try an older version or try TWRP recovery for Pixel 2XL, for adb sideload it should not make a difference if you use TWRP or LineageOS.

Comment: I cannot flash anything, seemt that the device is readonly now (as `4ee0` suggests...)

Comment: ... I initially could flash a boot img but no more since then...

Comment: instead of lineage bootloader I've been able to flash (with fastboot) twrp. It still cannot be seen through adb... Perhaps there is smthg to do with udev rrules ... ?