# Is there a way to enable ADB from the phone's terminal

Tags: adb, lineageos

[I'm stuck at trying to install LineageOS on my Pixel](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253953/44325): unfortunately `adb` cannot see my phone and I have flashed the bootloader and wiped the previous system.

How can I activate USB debugging programmatically? I can access the phone filesystem as root from the Recovery ROM.

Comment: What do you want to do with adb access? Assuming you have unless died the bootloader for installing Lineage OS all your data is wiped. In my opinion you should better try to get the phone back in a "stock state" to see if it still works as expected and retry installing Lineage OS. Pixel stock images that can be installed via fastboot are provided by Google. Once you have a working system you can copy LineageOS zip file to sdcard shared storage and retry LineageOS install from recovery without needing adb.

Comment: @Robert Yes I thought of doing smthg like that indeed. What's the process to install stock ROM ? I got a OTA zip at google for my taimen. Is it the possible to install it with fastboot ? How ?

Comment: With an unlocked bootloader I would recommend the non-OTA package as it directly installs via fastboot. Or you try the web-installer. But always make sure there is no USB hub between your computer and the phone, even not dockingstation. To my experience with something in between the USB connection flashing will fail at a high chance.